# SharePoint Online 2013 removed permission for all groups/users

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, list, access-denied

While working with Access Request list of a site, in the list permissions, I stopped inheriting permissions from parent and then accidentally removed permission for all the groups & users. How can I revert this? Does the Site-collection Admin still has access to this list?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you need to restore inheritance .

- Go to the list, library, or survey and open it.
- Go to the Permissions page to the list, library, or survey using the steps in the section above.
- On the Permissions tab (for a list or a library), click Delete unique permissions.

[image]

For more details check the [reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-permissions-for-a-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#BKMK_Restore)

Comment: Hi @M.Qassas, thanks for your response. Since I have removed the permission for all users/groups, I don't have access to the list.

Comment: Are you tried to use Site collection administrator / or the farm account I also updated my answer to can achieve it using power shell

Comment: That PS is for on-prem, the question states Online

Comment: Not yet. Will try and let you know.